# How to hide submenu when user clicks option, but still display when user hovers over menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

Currently my submenu displays on hover and hides when I click on a submenu item. This is great. Problem is, when I hover back over the top level menu it doesn't display the submenu after I click on a submenu item.

I would really like for the submenu to hide when the user clicks a submenu item, but I want it to display again if the user hovers over the top level menu again. Any ideas on how to fix this? Would really like a plain JS or css solution to this, no jquery please.

I did try to google this, but all I found were people trying to permanently hide a sub menu item that was clicked. I also read that innerHTML would remove all child elements so I moved my item text into buttons rather than the li elements and changed it to innerText instead of innerHTML.

```js
function classSelect(profession) {
  document.getElementById('dropDownSelections').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('classMenuHeader').innerText = profession;
}

function toggleMenu() {
  document.getElementById('dropDownSelections').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.dropDownList {
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropDownList ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  overflow: visible;
}
.dropDownList ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  overflow: visible;
}
.dropDownList ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: visible;
}
.dropDownList ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropDownList ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropDownList ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}
.dropDownList ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
.dropDownList a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}
.dropdownList input[type="button"] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropDownList">
  <ul>
    <li onmoustover="toggleMenu();"><a href="#" id="classMenuHeader" onclick="return false;">Select Class</a>
      <ul id="dropDownSelections">
        <li onclick="classSelect('item1');">
          <input type="button" value="item1" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item2');">
          <input type="button" value="item2" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item3');">
          <input type="button" value="item3" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item4');">
          <input type="button" value="item4" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item5');">
          <input type="button" value="item5" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item6');">
          <input type="button" value="item6" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item7');">
          <input type="button" value="item7" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item8');">
          <input type="button" value="item8" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I kinda butchered your js and html a bit, but this should work

HTML

```
<div class="dropDownList">
  <ul id="classDropDownList">
      <li><a href="#" id="classMenuHeader">Select Class</a>
      <ul id="dropDownSelections">
        <li onclick="classSelect('item1');">
          <input type="button" value="item1" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item2');">
          <input type="button" value="item2" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item3');">
          <input type="button" value="item3" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item4');">
          <input type="button" value="item4" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item5');">
          <input type="button" value="item5" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item6');">
          <input type="button" value="item6" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item7');">
          <input type="button" value="item7" />
        </li>
        <li onclick="classSelect('item8');">
          <input type="button" value="item8" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    document.getElementById('classDropDownList').onmouseover = function(){
        document.getElementById('dropDownSelections').style.display = 'block';
    }

    document.getElementById('classDropDownList').onmouseout = function(){
        document.getElementById('dropDownSelections').style.display = 'none';
    }

});

function classSelect(profession) {
  document.getElementById('dropDownSelections').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('classMenuHeader').innerText = profession;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to be working. It's functioning the same as what I had before. It seems, the top level LI is taking up the full height of the sub menu, causing it to always think the LI is being hovered even when on the submenu. When I have your event listener active, it will not hide anything, but when I remove that it hides the sub menu, but the sub menu won't come back when I mouseover.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your requirement. Possible for you to do a quick mock-up image on what you wanted to archive?

Also here is the fiddle that I was playing around with

https://jsfiddle.net/su5hsahq/1/

Comment: Oh, it works in the jsfiddle... I'll have to tinker around with my code more later. Thank you! Sorry about my previous comment, I must have missed something when changing my code.

Comment: You are welcome! I think it might have something to do with the placement of the javascript (the script placement in the jsfiddle is in the body tag).

Its rare to see someone working on a plain javascript nowadays though. :)